# Order of second coat painting

Tags: painting

When painting with a roller, the perimeters are first painted with a brush.  If one is to apply a second coat on the perimeters, should the first roller coat be applied before the second coat on the perimeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I roll everything to achieve a consistent finish, or "stipple". Thus, I roll my brushed edging immediately after application, and along with the rest of the rolling, regardless of the coat number. The longer you wait to roll your edging the more likely visible brush marks become.

If you don't care about brush marks, the wall doesn't care in which order you paint it.